# Animating heatmap with python seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

This is driving me crazy. I'm trying to create an animation of a heatmap where every frame shows a different time stamp. I have created the data structures, imported ffmpeg, and I tried another package too (celluloid that seems very good). I tried an example with a simple line plot and it does animate. The result is always the same: I get the last frame, not an animation. Here is my code in case anyone can spot the error... Thank you in advance.

------------- Code --------------

```
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML

data2 = df[['ProducerName', 'MemOccupied']]
data2 = data2.sort_index().sort_values('ProducerName', kind='mergesort')
data2 = data2[['MemOccupied']]
fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)
df_heatmap = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df_heatmap = df_heatmap.dropna()
df_heatmap = df_heatmap.resample('1T').mean()
count = df_heatmap.count()
index_series = df_heatmap.index

def init():
    #plt.clf()
    ax = sns.heatmap(data2[data2.index == index_series[1]], cbar_kws={'label': 'Memory Occupied (GB)'}, cmap='Blues_r')
    ax.set(ylabel=None)
    #return (ax,)

def animate(i):
    plt.clf()
    ax = sns.heatmap(data2[data2.index == index_series[i]], cbar_kws={'label': 'Memory Occupied (GB)'}, cmap='Blues_r')
    ax.set(ylabel=None)
    #return (ax,)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = animate, init_func=init, frames=count-1,repeat = True, interval = 200)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

Comment: Do you have some data, even fictif data would be helpful.

Comment: Sure the data itself is not important so you can just randomly generate it:
```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df = df.rename(columns={'A': 'ProducerName'})
df = df.rename(columns={'B': 'MemOccupied'})
```